# Is there such a thing as a dictionary that lists all the words for a given morpheme?

Tags: morphemes

I've just discovered what a morpheme is. The article I read on the subject listed many morphemes and gave examples words of each type but the list of words for each morpheme was not exhaustive. I've Google searched for lists of words by morpheme and looked on Amazon to see if they sell dictionaries that might give such information, but I can't find any. I would find it interesting to be able to search for words in both directions i.e. I would like to have a list of words for each morpheme but I would also find it interesting to see each word that consists of morphemes being broken down into its constituent morphemes. Is anyone aware of any such listings and where they may be obtained?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it may help.  If it does lead to an answer, can you can you share your discovery here, please. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online

Comment: If such a thing exists, I'd expect it to be found in technical resources for linguists. So maybe you'll be able to find an answer on linguistics.SE.

Comment: Hugh, on:
http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online
under "corpora" > "Corpa Concordance English" you get directed to:
http://lextutor.ca/conc/eng/
which is very good for finding a string of letters contained (starting, within or ending) in a corpus of words so it can be used, for example, to find all words containing the string of letters "leg."
It's not perfect but it helps me identify the words that contain a given morpheme so thanks for putting me onto this.

Answer (score 2):

The headmaster of the Maple Hayes school for dyslexic students is currently compiling a morpheme dictionary.
https://maplehayeshallschool.squarespace.com/about/

Comment: I think this is a potentially useful answer.  Do you know if the dictionary has been published?  You might edit to link to the other book the author has written https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjyjpVVmEkE or to the video explanation of morphemes linked on the school website. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjyjpVVmEkE